# SQL : Return the records that are the oldest in date

Tags: sql

So.....

I have a table (`WOSTATUS`). With the columns (`WONUM`, `STATUS`, `CHANGEDATE`).

Now there are multiple statuses to a `WONUM`. The one I am interested in is status `ACTION`. However the `WONUM` can be set to ACTION multiple times in its life, and in this table each time it is set to ACTION it becomes a new row.

What I want is a list of the `WONUM` when it was **first** put to ACTION. The date is recorded in `CHANGEDATE`.

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Sounds like you should run a groupby and order by Action

Comment: @indofraiser I have used Orderby CHANGEDATE, however that just returns all rows and then sorts them descending. I just want the row with the earliest date to return.

Comment: can you provided some example of data that is in table and expected result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT WONUM, MIN(CHANGEDATE) 
FROM WOSTATUS 
WHERE STATUS = 'ACTION' 
GROUP BY WONUM, STATUS
```

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand it correctly that each time the status changes, you add a new row to the table. And you want the `WONUM` of the entries when the first status was `'ACTION'` ?

In that case try the following:

```
SELECT WONUM
FROM WOSTATUS
WHERE (SELECT TOP 1 STATUS
       FROM WOSTATUS T
       WHERE T.WONUM = WONUM
       ORDER BY CHANGEDATE) = 'ACTION'
```